# Find the maximum of an atom in clingo

Tags: max, answer-set-programming, clingo

I am a starter with clingo and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the max value of a given atom.
e.g.

```
x(1..9).
x_max(X) :- x(X), x(Y), X>Y.
```

The result I would like to have in this case would be `x_max(9)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
max_x(X) :- x(X), #max {XX,1:x(XX)} = X.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: I don't see why there is XX instead of X

Answer (score 0):

I'll first modify a bit the first answer and then provide a more general example.

```
x(1..9). % equivalent to x(1). x(2). [...] x(9).

% find the max across predicates x
x_max(X) :- x(X), X = #max{X_i: x(X_i)}. 

%%% entails x_max(9)
```

The `X_i` is the internal variable across which the max is computed. This value is assigned to `X`. The `x(X)` is a (safe) constraint necessary for how the solver works.

We consider now a more complex predicate of the form `r(X, Y)`:

```
r(1, 3). r(3, 3). r(3, 2). r(5, 6). r(5, 3). 

% find the max across the parameters X
xmax(X) :- r(X, _), X = #max{X_i: r(X_i, _)}. 

%%% entails xmax(5) 

% find the max across the parameters Y 
ymax(Y) :- r(_, Y), Y = #max{Y_i: r(_, Y_i)}. 

%%% entails ymax(6) 

% find the max across Y conditioned by parameter X
ymax_x(Y, X) :- r(X, Y), Y = #max{Y_i: r(X, Y_i)}. 

%%% entails ymax_x(3,1) ymax_x(3,3) ymax_x(6,5)
```